# Iterate through offline large JSON file

Tags: android, json, iteration, large-files

I have an offline large `.json` file that contains `all countries` with `all cities`

The file size is around `2mb size` ,  [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json)

**my need**

When I type **ind** my first `AutoCompleteTextview` should pupulate **India**

When I type **mum** my second `AutoCompleteTextview` should pupulate **Mumbai**

for this I have to iterate throughout the `large .json file`

**what i tried**

I came across `JACKSON` JSON STREAMING API , but nor sure how to incorporate for my case

Comment: Don't forget Google's [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) which is also a very good framework

Answer (score 0):

1. Save Json file into assets
2. Read Json from assets to string
3. Then parse json to Model class using Gson library
4. Once model is ready then populate Auto Complete Text View

Comment: can u please help me out with this " Then parse json to Model class using Gson library "

Comment: Once you load json from assets. parse json to model class  using Gson Library

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();
YourModel model = gson.fromJson(jsonLine, YourModel .class);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing through the JSON file everytime the user types in the AutoCompleteTextView, parse the file when the user opens your application and store the country names in an Arraylist or something. And when the user types a name, search in these ArrayLists. It will be much faster than parsing through the whole JSON file everytime.